# speech to text api other language android

Tags: java, android, google-api, speech-to-text

I develop android application that can recognize speech in Mandarin, then yield text. But i can't find how to do that. Can someone give me example code of speech recognition in other language(mandarin, france, etc) ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtSpeechInput;
private ImageButton btnSpeak;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    // hide the action bar
    getActionBar().hide();

    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listen();
        }
    });

}



private static int SR_CODE = 123;

/**
 * Initializes the speech recognizer and starts listening to the user input
 */
private void listen()  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        //Specify language
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
        // Specify language model
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        // Specify how many results to receive
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
        // Start listening
        startActivityForResult(intent, SR_CODE);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SR_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            // Retrieves the best list SR result
            ArrayList<String> nBestList = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            String bestResult = nBestList.get(0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bestResult,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Reports error in recognition error in log
            Log.e("Log", "Recognition was not successful");
        }
    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Did the solution provided work?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just opened this question. It's work like my post in below. I don't know why {locale.SIMPLEFIED_CHINESE} can not yield chinese word. But thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE) when you call the recognizer.

So an example in simplified chinese will be:

```
private static int SR_CODE = 123;


/**
     * Initializes the speech recognizer and starts listening to the user input
     */
    private void listen()  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        //Specify language
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE)
        // Specify language model
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        // Specify how many results to receive
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
        // Start listening
        startActivityForResult(intent, SR_CODE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SR_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)  {
                if(data!=null) {
                //Retrieves the best list SR result
                ArrayList<String> nBestList = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
               String bestResult = nBestList.get(0);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bestResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;              
            }else {         
                //Reports error in recognition error in log
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "Recognition was not successful");
            }

    }
```

Comment: It's an integer constant used in the onActivityResult callback. I've updated my answer. Let me know if the problem isn't resolved

Comment: i have done your code. but it always shows in English. I've updated my question code like your code. But big thanks for helping me

Comment: Did you try other languages. Example: "fr_FR" instead of Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE. Note that it'll run only if Google supports that language. Also note that starting from 4.4, Android allows multiple languages to be selected in Settings, and will always try to "guess" the language according to system settings and completely ignore the EXTRA_LANGUAGE extra

Answer (score 5):

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "zh");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "zh");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES, "zh");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,"zh");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "zh");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS, "zh");
```