# how to convert speech into text in android in different languages please give your valuable suggestions to implement

Tags: java, android, android-studio

how to convert speech into text in android in different languages

Advance Thanks

Comment: see this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194988/speech-to-text-api-other-language-android

Answer (score 2):

Refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/), it shows a basic way on how to have a speech to text in android

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/) link to Convert Speech to text.