# Android multiple language support to dynamic content

Tags: java, android, localization

I want to support my app to multiple languages.I implemented for static strings through localization but what i want is if user change app language from English to any other and input Edit text with google voice then that string will b shown in user selected language rather than English language. As in google translate app happens,i input text by voice and what result is found that string is in that selected language.
Can anyone please help me??

Answer (score 0):

There is limited supported language but you need to invoke Speech Recognition by putting extra intent parameter

```
 private void listen()  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        //Specify language
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE)
        // Specify language model
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        // Specify how many results to receive
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
        // Start listening
        startActivityForResult(intent, SR_CODE);
    }
```

[check full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194988/speech-to-text-api-other-language-android)